# .Net 6 not installed on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I built a desktop application using C# and .Net 6. I also made an installer so that the app can be installed on an other computer. The problem is that when a tried to launch the app on my second laptop, .Net 6 was not installed and I had to install it myself. So, is there any method to avoid this error or .Net 6 must be installed manually ?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what kind of app it is,. have you tried the self contained publish method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: I haven't tried. I just seen the documentation you shared. I will try. Thanks.